# Efficient way to check data toggle

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

```
var navbarCollapse = true;

var main = function() {
    $('.navbar-toggle').click(function() {
        if (navbarCollapse == true) {
            $('.container').animate({ marginTop: '+300px' }, 400);
            navbarCollapse = false;
        } else {            
            $('.container').animate({ marginTop: '40px' }, 400);
            navbarCollapse = true;
        }
    });
};
```

Is there another way that more efficient to check if navbar collapse is collapsed or not rather than using variable?

Comment: add a class and use `.toggleClass()` depending if the exist exists you can do your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just check the current `margin-top` value and use a ternary expression to set it based on that. Try this:

```
var main = function() {
    $('.navbar-toggle').click(function() {
        var $container = $('.container');
        var currentMargin = parseInt($container.css('margin-top'), 10);
        $container.animate({ 
            marginTop: currentMargin == 40 ? '+300px' : 40;
        });
    });
};
```

Better still, set the margin in a class with a `transition` rule to cover the animation and then toggle that on and off in your JS:

```
.container {
    margin-top: 40px;
    transition: margin 0.4s;
}
.container.expand {
    margin-top: 340px;
}
```

```js
var main = function() {
    $('.navbar-toggle').click(function() {
        $('.container').toggleClass('expand');
    });
};
```

Comment: Because it means that rule is of a higher specificity and will be applied over the same style set in another rule (in this case `.container')

Comment: I thought in css itself, if there are css classes with same level of specificity, the last one will be applied....am i wrong?

Comment: Most often that is the case, but it is in no way guaranteed.